# Why does a BoxDecoration increase GestureDetector's area of effect?

Tags: dart, flutter

With the following code, the GestureDetector is only registering taps in the upper left corner of the image.

```
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {

  void tap(TapDownDetails details) {
    print('${details.globalPosition}');
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: new Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: new GestureDetector(
        onTapDown: tap,
        child: new Center(
          child: new Container(
            height: 400.0,
            width: 400.0,
            child: new FittedBox(
              fit: BoxFit.fill,
              child: new Image.asset('assets/900px-image.png'),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I would like it to register taps anywhere in the box containing the Image.  However, I did discover that if I add a BoxDecoration to the Container containing the Image, it does register taps anywhere in the box.  How does GestureDetector determine its area of effect and why does the BoxDecoration change it?

```
  body: new GestureDetector(
    onTapDown: tap,
    child: new Center(
      child: new Container(
        height: 400.0,
        width: 400.0,
        decoration: new BoxDecoration(color: Colors.transparent),
        child: new FittedBox(
          fit: BoxFit.fill,
          child: new Image.asset('assets/900px-image.png'),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ),
```

Answer (score 3):

This behavior can be changed by GetureDetector `behavior` property.

For GestureDetector to register click on opaque BoxDecoration you should set it value to `HitTestBehavior.opaque` or `HitTestBehavior.translucent`